# Create an 2-D empty array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to use `union` in Matlab to merge a series of 1-by-2 arrays for example `[1,2]` to an empty 2-D array `U`, i.e., `U = union(U,[1,2],'rows');` But I'm confused how to initialize `U`, because `U=[]` didn't work, no luck with `U=[[],[]]` either. I tried `U = [U,[1,2]]`, it works only when the 1-by-2 arrays in the series are all unique, or I would have duplicate entries in `U`.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get all the *unique* 1x2 arrays in a 2-D matrix? First, create a big 2-D array of all 1x2 arrays (including duplicates), then call [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html).

```
C = unique(A,'rows')
```

As for using `union`, there is no way to have a empty 1x2 array. What you can do instead is initialize `U` to be the same as your first 1x2 array. Then loop over all the other 1x2 arrays and use `union` to build your output.

```
U = union(U, [1,2], 'rows')
```

Comment: There is an overhead to `unique`, so don't want to cost that much.

Comment: @DavidTan What makes you think that `union` is more efficient?

Comment: you are right, I just tried tic/toc, unique is faster. However, I do want to learn how to do that using union, coz that looks more straightforward to me.